# What are the options for cross-org use of a dev hub?

Tags: salesforcedx, dev-hub

We (a salesforce development and support team) have several orgs, with varying schemas for varying companies with *some* cross-org work. I've seen a fair few of the dreamforce videos (none of which have discussed a multiple org situation, only prod/sandbox/development flavours of the same org) and have successfully deployed a package to a scratch org through CLI, so have gone through initial 'thinking' steps and am now trying to work out what the future setup looks like.

A dev hub is set up for a single org (I think?), based on https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm

Given this, do we:

1. Create a **dev hub per org**, and manage any cross-org work manually.
2. Create a **single dev hub** in one of the orgs, and treat this as our 'team' hub (I think this will create issues with creating scratch orgs?).
3. Have a new hub, in a new master org of some kind.
4. Another option?

[Perhaps the underlying question is - does it matter if you have multiple dev hubs? Do they need to be related?]

(aside: We're looking into our VCS options, but I'd like to ask this *without* focusing on the VCS question yet (taking the approach of introducing DX elements in a staggered way) as I want to take advantage of existing internal VCS options that aren't in my direct control.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dev Hub is set up for a single org. It does not matter if you have multiple Dev Hubs, and they don't have to be related to one another.

I think the most important factors here will be (1) scratch org limits are applied on a per-instance basis; and (2) your clients (and their compliance people) probably would not want any exposure of their development work to someone else's org, as being hosted in a scratch org that's linked to a Dev Hub attached to another company's org.

I would go for option 1, bearing in mind that the source of truth is your VCS, and cross-org work could (for example) be checked in to a shared *repository*, while being deployed individually to each scratch org. While I have not tried it myself, you might be able to do something clever with Git submodules here.

Comment: This brings up a potentially important point for transparency for partners who may want to have a central dev hub that potentially stores the auth credentials for several customers.